# Understanding an SQL Alias

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql, alias

I'm new to SQL.
I've read the book called 'Sams Teach Yourself Oracle PL/SQL in 10 minutes'.
I found it very interesting and easy to understand. There was some information on aliases but when I started doing exercises I came across an alias I don't know the purpose of.

Here is the cite http://www.sql-ex.ru/ and here is the database schema http://www.sql-ex.ru/help/select13.php#db_1, just in case. I'm working with the computer firm database i.e database number 1. The task is:

**To find the makers producing PCs but not laptops.**

Here is one of the solutions:

```
SELECT DISTINCT maker
           FROM Product AS pcproduct
          WHERE type = 'PC' 
            AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT maker
                              FROM Product
                             WHERE type = 'laptop' 
                               AND maker = pcproduct.maker
                           );
```

The question is: **Why do we need to alias product as pc_product and make the comparison 'maker = pc_product.maker' in the subquery?**

Comment: Wouldn't you be tempted to try it wothout the alias, and see what happens?

Comment: I already tried it, the output list is empty

Comment: So now you know why you need the alias ;-)

Comment: C'mon man, it's the worst explanation I've ever seen :)

Comment: The output list is empty because the subquery assumes you want to select maker from product (instead of productpc)

Comment: But it is the very same table, what's the difference between the product and productpc tables?

Comment: One is filtered on 'PC'. The other is filtered on 'laptop'.

Comment: But it is the same table, why can't I filter it without aliasing?

Comment: It's not the same table. It's too different subsets of the same table.

Comment: Can you tell me the order of evaluation? The output of the inner query is the table of the makers who produce laptops. Why do we need to check them against the table that we already used in "FROM" to check?

Comment: We can infer that MySQL resolves the subquery first. If it was the other way around, it would produce an error: `Column 'maker' in field list is ambiguous`

Comment: May I chat with you somehow?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177028/discussion-between-dmitrii-and-strawberry).

Comment: No, if you're still not getting it, I've obviously failed as an instructor. Probably time to move on with someone else!

Comment: @Dmitrii: Don't think *tables*, think *records*. For one PC *record* found we look up all *records* in the same table, in order to see if there is a laptop record for the same maker. The PC record and the laptop record are two different records from the same table. We can get the PC record's maker with `pcproduct.maker` and the laptop record's one with `product.maker` (or simply `maker`, because we are inside the laptop subquery).

Comment: I prefer to think of 'instances of tables'

Comment: The accepted answer on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52231927/tsql-subquery-behavior) points to some relevant documentation on the implicit qualification that database engines implement for ambiguous aliases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accessing the table twice, once in the main query, one in the sub query.

In the main query you say: Look at each record. Dismiss it, if the type doesn't equal 'PC'. Dismiss it, if you find a record in the table for the same maker with type 'laptop'.

In order to ask for the **same maker**, you must compare the maker of the main query's record with the records of the subquery. Both stem from the same table, so `where product.maker = product.maker` would be ambiguous. (Or rather the DBMS would assume you are talking about the subquery record, because the expression is inside the subquery. `where product.maker = product.maker` would hence be true, and you'd end up checking only whether there is at least one laptop in the table, regardless of the maker.)

So when dealing with the same table twice in a query, give at least on of them an alias in order to tell one record from the other.

Anyway for the given query I'd also qualify the other column in the expression for readability:

```
AND product.maker = pcproduct.maker
```

or even

```
 FROM Product laptopproduct
WHERE type = 'laptop' 
  AND laptopproduct.maker = pcproduct.maker
```

---

On a sidenote: The query looks for makers that produce PCs, but no laptops. I'd prefer asking for this with aggregation:

```
select maker
from product
group by maker
having sum(type = 'PC') > 0
   and sum(type = 'laptop') = 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

Because in the inner query there are columns, which are named exactly the same as those in outer query (due to the fact that you use the same table there).

Since outer query columns are available in the inner query, there must be a distinction, which column you want, without alias, you'd write in the inner query `maker = maker`, which would be always true.

Answer (score 1):

That query can be understood as :

> Gimme the maker's that have products of the 'PC' type, but where a
>   product of the 'laptop' type doesn't exist for that maker.

Including the tablename or alias name is sometimes needed when the same column names are used in more than 1 table.
So that the optimizer will know from which table the column is used.

It's not some smart AI that could guess that a criteria as
`WHERE x = x`
would actually mean
`WHERE table1.x = table2.x`

But more often, shorter alias names are used.
To increase readability and make the SQL more concise.

For example.  The following two queries are equivalent.

Without aliases:

```
SELECT myawesometableone.id, mysecondevenmoreawesometable.id, 
       mysecondevenmoreawesometable.col1
FROM myawesometableone
JOIN mysecondevenmoreawesometable on mysecondevenmoreawesometable.one_id = myawesometableone.id
```

With aliases:

```
SELECT t1.id, t2.id, t2.col1
FROM myawesometableone AS t1
JOIN mysecondevenmoreawesometable AS t2 on t2.one_id = t1.id
```

Which SQL do you think looks better?

As for why that `maker = pc_product.maker` is used inside the EXISTS?
That's how the syntax for EXISTS works.
You establish a link between the query in the EXISTS and the outer query.
And in that case, that link is the "maker" column.

Comment: Why do we need this: AND maker = pcproduct.maker?

Comment: Because you need to check if such a type exists for the SAME maker.  Without it, it would be like asking "where not a laptop type exists for ANY maker".

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't detract from the other (correct) answers, but an easier to follow example might be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT pcproduct.maker
           FROM Product AS pcproduct
          WHERE pcproduct.type = 'PC' 
            AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT internalproduct.maker
                              FROM Product AS internalproduct
                             WHERE internalproduct.type = 'laptop' 
                               AND internalproduct.maker = pcproduct.maker
                           );
```